# uWSGI touch-reload feature not working with 100% CPU

Tags: freebsd, cpu-usage, jail, uwsgi

On my development box, I have configured uWSGI to reload every time a file gets touched (using the --touch-reload  command line argument).
When I specify a non-existent file, I get a warning in the uWSGI logs. If I specify an existing file (say, `/data/reload.uwsgi`), I get nothing in the logs, meaning the settings *might* be OK.

Here's the problem: whenever I `touch /data/reload.uwsgi`, uWSGI doesn't reload. Logs don't show anything special (browsing the sources show I should get some kind of acknowledgment that the monitored file has been touched).

There is one thing though: all uwsgi processes start taking all available CPU power, until I stop the service.

uWSGI still works, but with the "old" Python code, not the reloaded one.

What am I missing? Is this a bug or something?

Thanks in advance,

Romain

---

By the way I'm running `uWSGI 0.9.7.2` on `FreeBSD 8.2 AMD64` with `Python 2.7.1`. uWSGI and Python are running inside a **jail**.

I've tried files like `/data/reload.uwsgi` or `/tmp/reload.uwsgi`, none of them work. I even tried to chown those files to the `www` user (the one who's running uwsgi processes), without success.
For the record, here's the command line in `/etc/rc.conf` to run the uWSGI service:

```
uwsgi_flags="-p 2 -M -t 30 -C --pythonpath /data/app -w <APPNAME> --uid www --gid www -L -d /var/log/uwsgi.log --post-buffering 8192 --touch-reload /data/reload.uwsgi"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug with FreeBSD, check the latest tip, it has been fixed

Comment: Oh yeah, a very small change indeed!
Thanks, I'll check that once the 0.9.7.3 port is available!